# How to ignore directories properly using egit in ADT?

Tags: android, git, github

I/m using egit plugin in latest ADT. Although I set proper .ignore file in github, and set ignore in egit menu, the directories I wanna igore are still committed to github.Is there sth. wrong in my project configure?

.gitignore in github/Myproject:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/
```

.gitignore in local/Myproject/3.9/:

```
/gen
/bin
```

Comment: Adding folders to `gitignore` does not remove them from repository, it prevents you from adding them. So if you already have committed the folders, you need to remove them.

Comment: remove them? Should I delete them directly on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove them? Should I delete them directly on github?

You should remove them on your local clone:

```
git rm --cached -r aFolderToIgnore
```

Then you can commit and push:

- GitHub will reflect the removal of those folders
- your `.gitignore` will be respected